# Need to split up a file into multiple files using DOS commands

Tags: file, split, dos

I have a txt file with lines delimited by `<` and `>`. Each line begins with `<` and ends with `>` (quotes not included in the file).

I need to split up each line within these tags to a new file using DOS commands. There are different symbols like `|` and spaces in each line which should be ignored.

Only beginning `<` and ending `>` should be taken into account for creating new files.

How can this be done?

Comment: DOS command FINDSTR contains a regular expression search that can find lines enclosed within < > and can output those lines using the /X option to print those lines.  Those line could be redirected to a file using >output.txt as the last parameter however it doesn't provide any way to output those lines to separate files.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. RegExp work perfect except that they cannot go into separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should do it. File name may also be extracted from line content.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set IDX=1
for /f "delims=<> tokens=1" %%L in (myfile.txt) do (
echo %%L>file!IDX!.bat
set /A IDX+=1
)
```